# limit keyword support in DB2 latest version

Tags: db2

I could see limit keyword is supported in latest version v10.5.500.107 5 of db2 by default without setting MYS compatibility vector. My installation was DB2 Express-C. Is there any announcement for that? I couldn't find any online document.

**EDIT**

After the answer of Ian I checked the value of compatibility vector after unsetting it as below also.

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR= 
db2stop 
db2start
```

and found it was MYS. seems like it is default set to MYS. that's why it has limit keyword support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no change that I am aware of in Fixpack 5 to the requirement that the registry variable  `DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR` must be set to `MYS` for the `... LIMIT x OFFSET y` functionality to work.  (Unsetting it in FP5 still results in an error if you try to use `LIMIT` / `OFFSET`).

You may want to look to see if `DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR` is set in the global registry.

Notice that running `db2set` alone does not show `DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR`:

```
$ db2set
DB2COMM=TCPIP
DB2AUTOSTART=YES
```

While running `db2set -all` does, since it's set at the global level:

```
$ db2set -all
[i] DB2COMM=TCPIP
[i] DB2AUTOSTART=YES
[g] DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS
[g] DB2SYSTEM=host1
[g] DB2INSTDEF=db2inst1
```